# Getting 403 when trying to invoke api through Global Accelerator

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to use AWS CDK with Typescript to create my infrastructure. My high-level overview is as follows:
User --> Global Accelerator (DNS name) --> Application Load Balancer (one per region) --> Vpc Interface Endpoint --> Private API Gateway (REST) --> Lambda function (private subnet w/ egress)

My goal is to have one application load balancer (ALB) per region (in my case us-east-2 and us-west-1) and have each ALB connect to a VPC interface endpoint which will connect to my API Gateway and trigger a Lambda function. I want my Global Accelerator to route a user to the optimal endpoint.

Global Accelerator DNS Name: example123.awsglobalaccelerator.com

I am using Axios (Typescript) to send a request to my backend by using the Global Accelerator DNS name:

```
const { data } = await axios.post(
                'https://example123.awsglobalaccelerator.com/prod/auth/login',
                {},
                {
                    headers: {
                        Accept: 'application/json'
                    },
                    params: {
                        username: username,
                        password: password
                    },
                    httpsAgent: agent
                }
            );
```

Doing so gives me a 403 error, 'x-amzn-errortype': 'ForbiddenException'. If I provide x-apigw-api-id in the header it is able to run the function.
The only issue with this is is that I want users to hit the global accelerator endpoint and have them routed to the nearest, available endpoint with Global Accelerator. So the x-apigw-api-id could vary.

Why is this occurring?

Here is how I created my Lambda REST API

```
 this.endpoint = new apigateway.LambdaRestApi(this, 'HarvardMoveLabApi', {
      handler: new lambda.Function(this, 'DEFAULT', {
        codeSigningConfig: this.codeSigningConfig,
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
        handler: 'default' + '.handler', // File is addUserToTrackedUsers, function is handler
        code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambdas/handlers'), // Load from this directory
        layers: [],
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(30)
      }), 
      proxy: false,
      endpointConfiguration: {
        types: [ apigateway.EndpointType.PRIVATE ],
        vpcEndpoints: [this.vpc.apiEndpoint],
      },
      deployOptions: {
        stageName: 'prod',
        dataTraceEnabled: true
      },
      
      policy: new iam.PolicyDocument({ 
        statements: [
          /*
          new iam.PolicyStatement({
            principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal],
            actions: ['execute-api:Invoke'],
            resources: ['execute-api:*'],
            effect: iam.Effect.DENY,
            conditions: {
              StringNotEquals: {
                "aws:SourceVpce": this.vpc.apiEndpoint.vpcEndpointId
              }
            }
          }),
          */
          new iam.PolicyStatement({
            principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal],
            actions: ['execute-api:Invoke'],
            resources: ['*'],
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW
          }),
        ]
      })
    });
```

and here is how I created my individual Lambda functions

```
 new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(this.generateLambdaFunction(lambdaApiEndpoint, props.stage)), {
          requestParameters: paramters
        });

  generateLambdaFunction(lambdaApiEndpoint: LambdaApiEndpoint, stage: string) {

    const lambdaFunction = new lambda.Function(this, lambdaApiEndpoint.nameOfFunction, {
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
        codeSigningConfig: this.codeSigningConfig,
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
        handler: lambdaApiEndpoint.handlerName + '.handler', 
        code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambdas/handlers'),
        layers: lambdaApiEndpoint.layers,
        vpc: this.vpc.vpc,
        vpcSubnets: {
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
        },
        
        environment: {
...
        }
      });

    this.grantPermissionsForLambda(lambdaApiEndpoint, lambdaFunction);

    return lambdaFunction;
}
```

Here's where I create my VPC and VPC Interface Endpoint

```
this.vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, `MyVpc-${props.region}`, {

        cidr: '10.0.0.0/16',
        subnetConfiguration: [
            {
                cidrMask: 24,
                name: `private_with_nat-${props.region}`,
                subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
            },
            {
                cidrMask: 24,
                name: `nat_gateway-${props.region}`,
                subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
            }
        ],
        vpcName: 'example123',
        
    }); 

this.apiEndpoint = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(this, `ApiEndpoint-${props.region}`, {
        service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.APIGATEWAY,
        vpc: this.vpc,
        subnets: { subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS },
        privateDnsEnabled: true, 
        securityGroups: [sg],
    });
```

Here is the security group I have added to my ALB and VPC endpoint

```
const sg = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'SecurityGroup', {
        vpc: this.vpc,
        allowAllOutbound: true,
        securityGroupName: 'VpcEndpoint'
      });
      sg.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(), ec2.Port.tcp(443));
      sg.addEgressRule(ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(), ec2.Port.tcp(443));
```

Want the function to run but isn't. I think a better question might be:
How to hit a API Gateway endpoint through the VPC interface endpoint without the x-apigw-api-id? The reason I would like to omit x-apigw-api-id from my request is because I want Global Accelerator to find the best endpoint for me

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).